# My github stats level decrease from A+ to B, How should I do?

Tags: github

Perhaps because I push some same comment commit to fixed my Github actions errors.
How can I get the reason and how should I do something to restore?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T0E4.png)

What should I do can increase my github stats level?

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic here, not really about programming

Comment: I don't think so, It may be about code commit standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's because of the number of contributions he's made to repositories other than his own.
According to this link https://github.com/HwangTaehyun/github-repository-contribution-stats more than 2 equals B and more than 1000 is rank S.